There are at least 3 versions of a quote, with 2 having different attributions. What is the original, who said it, and what does the quote mean?
The following comes from a book by Jason Meyer, The End of the Law: Mosaic Covenant in Pauline Theology, pages 2 & 3 (B&H 2010).  It was about historical digging into those O.T. and N.T. themes. The quote that seems to have come down to today is:

Run, John, run, the Law commands,  But gives us neither feet nor
hands.  Far better news the Gospel brings,  It bids us fly and gives
us wings.

An earlier version of this is in Charles Spurgeon’s writings, The Salt-Cellars: Being a Collection of Proverbs, Together with Homely Notes Thereon, page 200 (London, Passmore & Alabaster, 1889) It goes:

Run, John and work, the Law commands, yet finds me neither feet nor
hands. But sweeter news the Gospel brings; it bids me fly and lends me
wings!”

Spurgeon attributes this to an English revivalist and hymn writer, John Berridge (1716 – 1793).
The third quote, however, is:

A rigid matter was the Law, demanding brick, denying straw. But when
with Gospel tongue it sings, it bids me fly and gives me wings.

This is ascribed to 17th-18th Century Scottish preacher, Ralph Erskine (1685 – 1752). I note its reference to the Israelites in Egypt being commanded to increase their brick-production, but this time they had to find their own straw to do so.
My question is two-fold: (1) to ask if anybody with knowledge of religious quotes from that era to clarify what would have been the original quote, and who originated that quote. Even if that cannot be done, I further ask (2) what would the quote actually mean to Protestant Christians from the end of the 17th century to the end of the 18th?

Can the title be updated with more context? Currently this is on HNQ without context.

@AndrewT. The title has a limit for number of characters. I already had to chop my original wording down to squeeze this one in. If you could say what the abbreviation 'HNQ' means, I might be able to deal with that, thanks!

Anne, the title is not clear at all.. How about "But sweeter news the gospel brings, it bids me fly and lends me wings - Who first said it, and what does it mean?"

@AndrewShanks Ah! The obvious often evades me! The Q now being concluded, I should not change it now, but will try to ask clearer questions in the future. And your answer was equally as good as the one given the Green Tick. Both, together give the fullest, best answer. I hope people looking at this appreciate both answers.

What would the quote actually mean to Protestant Christians from the end of the 17th century to the end of the 18th?

The ministry which, to myself, most outstandingly conveys the sentiments expressed in the verse above is the ministry of William Huntington, 1745-1813. See the Wikipedia link, but it is a biased article and not at all worthy of the man himself who is better known from his own books, of which I have twenty volumes.
I have gone to my library and picked a volume at random, then opened it at random and flicked through a few of his letters. There follows just an example of this rich ministry :
Posthumous Letters CXXXIII Dec 10, 1797 p336

We must be stript, and be brought down and humbled, which is the worst part of all the work ; and it is by the wrath, terrors, bondage and condemning power of the law, that this work is done ; and 'blessed is the man whom God chastens, and teaches him out of his law' ; 'for every one that hath heard and hath learned of the Father cometh unto me, saith Christ, 'and he that cometh unto me I will in no wise cast out'.
And when such a hunger and a thirst are created in the soul after Jesus, as that nothing but himself can satisfy, the soul is moved out of its place ; it is out of the flesh and on the road to Christ.

. . . .  p337

...thou wilt find if thou art diligent in reading and in prayer, that the further thou goest on in this way of seeking him, the brighter discoveries wilt thou have ; for those that follow Christ shall not abide in darkness, but they shall have the light of life.
Many promises will drop into thy mouth to plead, and into thy heart to prop it up; his garments will emit their fragrance, more and more, as thou approachest him, and will smell of myrrh, aloes and cassia ; and every word he speaks will make his blessed mouth more and more sweet.
This, together with the savour of his good ointments, and a few words in good season when thou art weary, will make him 'the fairest among ten thousand and the altogether lovely.


I totally forgot, in my haste to answer the question and type words out, that all of William Huntington's works have been placed online. I have just remembered . . . .
WHSS 'The Coalheaver' (For that is what he was before his conversion and call to the ministry of Christ.)
The 'SS' which WH added to himself, having no qualifications, means 'Sinner Saved'.

It originated with John Bunyan, 1628-1688.

Run, John, run! the law commands,
But gives us neither feet not hands.
Better news the Gospel brings,
It bids us fly and gives us wings.

But I think the following variant, also attributed to Bunyan, was the original:

To run and work the law commands,
But gives us neither feet nor hands.
But better news the Gospel brings, It bids us fly and gives us wings.

Post script
Mea culpa.  I'm going to completely backtrack on this.  I was searching on my phone and thought I would find proof once I had time to look on my laptop..  I can find no real evidence.  You can find it attributed to Bunyan in several places on the internet, but none of them provide any evidence.
There is no real evidence in favour of John Bunyan unless those who attribute it to him on the internet can provide their sources.
The best I can find is this cut and paste:
Sunday, June 05, 2016
A rigid master was the law
Back in October 2006, I posted a bit of poetry on Law and Grace, possibly written by John Bunyan, Ralph Erskine or John Fischer.
Last month I happened upon a post -- Run, John, Run -- The author wrote, "I’m not sure, however, Bunyan ever wrote this profound and pithy summary."
I found similar poems to the one I posted that October, but have not found an original source showing this is by Bunyan. Ralph Erskine has four lines that are similar, plus two lines in another poem with the same sentiment:
A rigid master was the law,
Demanding brick, denying straw;
But when with gospel-tongue it sings,
It bids me fly, and gives me wings.
Gospel Sonnets; Or, Spiritual Songs, In Six Parts, (The Eighteenth Edition, Ralph Erksine, Edinburgh: W. Darling, 1782, p. 305.)
By promised aid, but lo; the grievous law
demanding brick, won't aid her with straw
(The Sermons, and Other Practical Works, Volume X, Ralph Erskine, London: R. Baynes, 1821, p. 26; the "rigid master" poem is on p. 221)
I'm not sure when Gospel Sonnets; Or, Spiritual Songs was first published, but Ralph Erskine died in 1752, so what he wrote must have been written before then! "Faith, without trouble or fighting, is a suspicious faith; for true faith is a fighting, wrestling faith."
"Run, John, and work" appears as part of a 5 stanza hymn by John Berridge in his Sion's Songs, or Hymns: Composed for the Use of them that love and follow the Lord Jesus Christ in Sincerity (John Berridge, London: Vallance and Conder, 1785, Hymn 150, Page 203). When Charles H. Spurgeon mentioned this hymn, he credited it to Berridge (as did William Gadsby in his hymn book). Both Spurgeon and Gadsby were quite familiar with Bunyan's works. It would seem they wouldn't have mentioned that if it were by him.
Hymn 150
1. The law demands a weighty debt,
And not a single mite will bate; 
But gospel sings of Jesu’s blood,
And says it made the payment good.
2. The law provokes men oft to ill,
And churlish hearts makes harder still;
But gospel acts a kinder part,
And melts a most obdurate heart.
3. Run, John, and work, the law commands,
Yet finds me neither feet nor hands;
But sweeter news the gospel brings;
It bids me fly, and lends me wings.
4. Such needful wings, O Lord, impart,
To brace my feet, and brace my heart;
Good wings of faith, and wings of love
Will make a cripple sprightly move.
5. With these a lumpish soul may fly,
And soar aloft, and reach the sky;
Nor faint nor falter in the race,
But cheerly work, and sing of grace.
It is possible that both Erskine and Berridge based their pieces on an earlier work, or perhaps this portion of Berridge's hymn is derived from Erskine.
Posted by R. L. Vaughn
This is hymn 49 in Gadsby's Hymns, where the phrase is "Run, run, and work" the law commands.

Are you able to link to a source for this ? Or to cite a reference ?

@NigelJ - Sorry, I have backtracked on my answer with a postscript. I was too hasty.

Up-voted for the 'mea culpa' and for the postscript. Appreciated. A negative research is still research.

@NigelJ - Thanks!

Yes, you've gone over and beyond expectations here, Andrew, and your diligence in research (including back-tracking!) is exemplary. What a pity I cannot give two Green Ticks, for now I have a problem!
